# im not able to create an application

Tags: reactjs

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
throw err;
^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\chaitanya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `npx create-react-app my-app`

note that if you already installed `create-react-app` globally, uninstall it with `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` so that npx will always use the latest version

Answer (score 0):

You can install create-react-app module using

```
npm i create-react-app
```

and then try to create your project.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```